# Google maps Walking Directions Request returns traffic information error

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-directions-api

I currently have a problem with a google maps request i'm doing.

The folowing response returns a error i only epect for a request with mode=driving

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=52.224006,5.172508&destination=52.226956,5.163566&mode=walking&departure_time=1544004780&key=[KEY]
```

Error message:

```
{
    "error_message": "departure_time is in the past. Traffic information is only available for future and current times.",
    "geocoded_waypoints": [
        {},
        {}
    ],
    "routes": [],
    "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Is my request in correct? I validated it a few times now and i think its correct.

I know the error message is correct if i had used driving as mode. But i used walking.

From google documents page:

> For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the
>   departure_time to receive a route and trip duration (response field:
>   duration_in_traffic) that take traffic conditions into account. This
>   option is only available if the request contains a valid API key, or a
>   valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The
>   departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the
>   future. It cannot be in the past.

Comment: The time is wrong : 1544004780.  The error indicates the time is not valid.

Comment: I agree with you that thats the message. But this error should only appear if driving is chosen as mode. Not Walking.

From google: 
"For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the departure_time to receive a route and trip duration (response field: duration_in_traffic) that take traffic conditions into account. This option is only available if the request contains a valid API key, or a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past.
."

Comment: Is the time : 15:44:00.4780?  Is the time local or UTC?  Does it assume the time is Today since the date is missing.  Maybe it wants a date and assume the number is 15/44/0047

Comment: According to Google the timestamp should be in seconds from 1-1-1970. This date is from 5-12-2018.

Comment: So did you run before 12/5/18 15:13 (UTC)?

Comment: Yes I did and then it did work. But that's not my real question. Correct me if i wrong but this error should only show if im using traffic information and traffic information should only show if mode=driving (google doc: The travel mode parameter is driving, or is not specified (driving is the default travel mode).) But i have walking specified. I'm not expecting this error.